# Annotate functions with macros

Tags: c, macros, flutter

I'm looking into Flutters embedder API because I might be calling it via Rust in an upcoming project and find this:

```
FLUTTER_EXPORT
FlutterResult FlutterEngineShutdown(FlutterEngine engine);
```

The `FLUTTER_EXPORT` part is (from what I can see) a macro defined as:

```
#ifndef FLUTTER_EXPORT
#define FLUTTER_EXPORT
#endif // FLUTTER_EXPORT
```

I'm by no means a C guru but I have done my fair share of C programming but have never had the opportunity to use something like this. What is it? I've tried to Google it but don't really know what to call it other than "annotation" which doesn't really feel like a perfect fit.

[Flutter embedder.h](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/4733e3373789894aa4f593137c6d440891d492a2/shell/platform/embedder/embedder.h)

Comment: Is your question *what is a macro* or *what does this macro lines do?*

Comment: Depending on platform functions in a library might need compiler-specific qualifiers. By having a macro such as `FLUTTER_EXPORT` is a handy way to do that. If being build by a compiler that needs these special qualifiers, then the macro will be defined with a body that expands to them,  otherwise it will expand as nothing.

Comment: This can be used with a static code analyzer. Or, the macro could actually expand to something else in different platforms, for instance on Windows you would need ad `__declexport` or something similar to export symbols from a dll.

Comment: Excuse the ambiguity of the question. Since the macro does not take a value (is not a symbolic constant) or does not seem to contain any code, why is it called before every function declaration in the header?

Comment: Like IharobAlAsimi said, the macro might be set by another header file that is only included when compiling on windows where it's value could be `__declexport`. That's why your header file might first check if it's already defined and if not, it defines an "empty" one.

Comment: It is likely so that you can use something like `__declspec(dllexport)` (or perhaps `__declspec(dllimport)`) in a Windows DLL.  There are a number of annotations that can be used to decorate functions in Windows (in particular; there are [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) in GNU C, and even in standard C with things like `_Noreturn`; see also [Visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility)).

Comment: It's defined as `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` at https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/e8526e6fd3c62f7fb0f7efb3601d5b7ecde277a8/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Headers/FlutterMacros.h#L10 . I'm not sure Flutter can be build on MSVC, but if it can there is probably somethnig which defines it to `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Answer (score 1):

Also as pointed out - these macro can't be expanded to something meaningful - for example if you write this macro couple of time it will affect nothing.

Another nice use can be - (useful in testing of code) from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)

You can pass `-DFLUTTER_EXPORT=SOMETHING` while using `gcc`. This will be useful in running your code for testing purposes without touching the codebase. Also this can be used in providing different kind of expnasion based on the compile time passed parameter - which can be used in different ways.

Also a significant part of my answer boasts of the visibility using the empty macro, gcc also provides a way to realize the same thing as described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) using `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` <sup>(as IharobAlAsimi/nemequ mentioned)</sup> (`-fvisibility=hidden`) etc for the macro `FLUTTER_EXPORT`. The name also gives us a idea that it might be necessary to add the attribute `__declspec(dllimport)` (which means it will be imported from a dll). An example regarding gcc's usage of visibility support over there will be helpful.

---

It can useful in associating some kind of debug operation like this (By this I mean that these empty macros can be used like this also - though the name suggests that this was not the intended use)

```
#ifdef FLUTTER_EXPORT
#define ...
#else
#define ...
#endif
```

Here `#define` here will specify some printing or logging macro. And if not defined then it will be replaced with something blank statement. `do{}while(0)` etc.

Comment: Note that this macro cannot expand to a statement.

Comment: It's the fact that the macro is "empty" that confused me.

Comment: @MasterBait.: Well like I said - if you write it and you will see that this expands to no statement - the only use i can think of is mentioned.

Comment: @MasterBait The macro can be defined at compile time too, for instance with *gcc* you can do `-DFLUTTER_EXPORT=SOMETHING` and it might be used like that in this case.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi.: Hey thanks...this was interesting. I guess even I used it once and forgot. :)

Comment: Now your answer is a lot better. But point out, that given the name `FLUTTER_EXPORT`, perhaps it really means exactly that. There is a *gcc* way to [control visibility of symbols](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) and similar features are present in MS C/C++ compiler.

Comment: I think he's suggesting that `FLUTTER_EXPORT` may be defined to `__declspec(dllexport)` when building on MSVC, or `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` on GCC. It may also be necessary to define it to `__declspec(dllimport)` (or maybe `extern`) sometimes when *consuming* the API, too… Based on the name, that would be my guess, too.

Comment: @nemequ.: Yes it seems you are right..I was reading the link mentioned in my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi.: I guess edit is making things clear.

Comment: dllexport isn't quite the same thing as default visibility (and dllimport is nothing like hidden visibility)… And, based on the name and usage, this macro has nothing to do with debugging statements.

Comment: @nemequ.: Yes I am going really weird over the sleepy edge..I edited that's why "default"...but I don't get this with debugging statements? I have used the similar thing for debugging. That's why I mentioned it. The question was initially why these macros exist...I stated that's why.

Comment: @nemequ.: I am open to your opinion...all i am saying is this similar thing can be used in testing ot debugging also (maybe it;s a stupid way - maybe there is much much better way to do it ) but there is a way to do it the way I mentioned like that too. What you said is much more relevant regarding `dllimport` in context of visibilty...You can let me know of your opinion.

Comment: @nemequ.: I get your concern - you are saying that `FLUTTER_EXPORT` might not have direct correspondence with debugging like I said - but it can be used as one (I have seen similar to it used like that)...I have eduted my answer to clarify that.

Comment: @nemequ, You might be right. I only know that on a Windows system you need to export dll symbols. But I have never been interested in GNU's visibility, which I don't fully know. I am gonna read about it right now and learn about it.

Comment: @nemequ.: Check the edit. I guess I get your earlier comment.

Comment: Okay, so my comments weren't going to fit in a… well, comment, so I banged out a quick answer. I think you mostly answered the original question, but a lot of stuff came up in the comments and in your answer that I wanted to address.

Comment: @nemequ.: I will go through your answer when I get time. On the other hand, I guess somebody downvoted - like 3 edits earlier. The answer is modified after that. I guess I will go through my points again. Because I guess none of them is incorrect. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a bit rambling, but I wanted to talk about some stuff that came up in the comments in addition to your initial question.

On Windows, under certain situations the compiler needs to be explicitly told that certain symbols are to be publicly exposed by a DLL. In Microsoft's compiler (heretofore referred to as MSVC), this is done by adding a [`__declspec(dllexport)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport) annotation to the function, so you would end up with something like

```
__declspec(dllexport)
FlutterResult FlutterEngineShutdown(FlutterEngine engine);
```

Alas, the declspec syntax is non-standard. While GCC does actually support it (IIRC it's ignored on non-Windows platforms), other conformant compilers may not, so it should *only* be emitted for compilers which support it. The path that the Flutter devs have taken is one easy way to do this; if `FLUTTER_EXPORT` isn't defined elsewhere, they simply define it to nothing, so that on compilers where `__declspec(dllexport)` is unnecessary the prototype you've posted would become

```
FlutterResult FlutterEngineShutdown(FlutterEngine engine);
```

But on MSVC you'll get the declspec.

Once you have the default value (nothing) set, you can start thinking about how to define special cases. There are a few ways to do this, but the most popular solutions would be to include a platform-specific header which define macros to the correct value for that platform, or to use the build system to pass a definition to the compiler (*e.g.*, `-DFLUTTER_EXPORT="__declspec(dllexport)"`). I'm prefer to keep logic in the code instead of the build system when possible to make it easier to reuse the code with different build systems, so I'll assume that's the method for the rest of the answer, but you should be able to see the parallels if you choose the build-system route.

As you can imagine, the fact that there is a default definition (which, in this case, is empty) makes maintenance easier; instead of having to define every macro in each platform-specific header, you only have to define it in the headers where a non-default value is required. Furthermore, if you add a new macro you needn't add it to every header immediately.

I think that's pretty much the end of the answer to your initial question.

Now, if we're not building Flutter, but instead using the header in a library which links to the Flutter DLL, `__declspec(dllexport)` isn't right. We're not exporting the `FlutterEngineShutdown` function in our code, we're **importing** it from a DLL. So, if we want to use the same header (which we do, otherwise we introduce the possibility of headers getting out of sync), we actually want to map `FLUTTER_EXPORT` to `__declspec(dllimport)`. AFAIK this isn't usually necessary even on Windows, but there are situations where it is.

The solution here is to define a macro when we're building Flutter, but never define it in the public headers. Again, I like to use a separate header, something like

```
#define FLUTTER_COMPILING

#include "public-header.h"
```

I'd also throw some include guards in, and a check to make sure the public API wasn't accidentally included first, but I'm to lazy to type it here.

Then you can define `FLUTTER_EXPORT` with something like

```
#if defined(FLUTTER_COMPILING)
  #define FLUTTER_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define FLUTTER_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

You may also want to add a third case, where neither is defined, for situations where you're building the Flutter SDK into an executable instead of building Flutter as a shared library then linking to it from your executable. I'm not sure if Flutter supports that or not, but for now let's just focus on the Flutter SDK as a shared library.

Next, let's look at a related issue: visibility. Most compilers which aren't MSVC masquerade as GCC; they define `__GNUC__`, `__GNUC_MINOR__`, and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` (and other macros) to the appropriate values and, more importantly, if they're pretending to be GCC ≥ 4.2 they support the visibility attribute.

Visibility isn't quite the same as dllexport/dllimport. Instead, it's more like telling the compiler whether the symbol is internal ("hidden") or publicly visible ("default"). This is a bit like the `static` keyword, but while `static` restricts a symbol's visibility to the current compilation unit (*i.e.*, source file), hidden symbols can be used in other compilation units but they're not exposed by the linker.

Hiding symbols which needn't be public can be a huge performance win, especially for C++ (which tends to expose a lot more symbols than people think). Obviously having a smaller symbol table makes the linking a lot faster, but perhaps more significant is that the compiler can perform a lot of optimizations which it can't or doesn't for public symbols. Sometimes this is as simple as inlining a function which otherwise wouldn't be, but another huge performance gain can come from the compiler being able to assume data from a caller is aligned, which in turn allows vectorization without unnecessary shuffling. Another might allow the compiler to assume that a pointer isn't aliased, or maybe a function is never called and can be pruned. Basically, there are **lots** of optimizations the compiler can only do if it knows it can see all the invocations of a function, so if you care about runtime efficiency you should never expose more than is necessary.

This is also a good chance to note that `FLUTTER_EXPORT` isn't a very good name. Something like `FLUTTER_API` or `FLUTTER_PUBLIC` would be better, so let's use that from now on.

By default, symbols are publicly visible, but you can change this by passing `-fvisibility=hidden` to the compiler. Whether or not you do this will determine whether you need to annotate public functions with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` or private functions with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`, but I would suggest passing the argument so that if you forget to annotate something you'll end up with an error when you try to use it from a different module instead of silently exposing it publicly.

Two other things also came up in the comments: debugging macros and function annotations. Because of where `FLUTTER_EXPORT` is used, we know it's not a debugging macro, but we can talk about them for a second anyways. The idea is that you can insert extra code into your compiled software depending on whether or not a macro is defined. The idea is something like this:

```
#if defined(DISABLE_LOGGING)
#  define my_log_func(msg)
#else
#  define my_log_func(msg) my_log_func_ex(expr)
#endif
```

This is actually a pretty bad idea; think about code like this:

```
if (foo)
  my_log_func("Foo is true!");

bar();
```

With the above definitions, if you compile with `DISABLE_LOGGING` defined, you'll end up with

```
if (foo)
  bar();
```

Which probably isn't what you wanted (unless you're entering an obfuscated C competition, or trying to insert a backdoor).

Instead, what you usually want is (as coderredoc mentioned) basically a no-op statement:

```
#if defined(DISABLE_LOGGING)
#  define my_log_func(msg) do{}while(0)
#else
#  define my_log_func(msg) my_log_func_ex(expr)
#endif
```

You may end up with a compiler error in some weird situations, but compile-time errors are vastly preferable to difficult-to-find bugs like you can end up with for the first version.

Annotations for static analysis is another situation which was mentioned in the comments, and it's something I'm a *huge* fan of. For example, let's say we have a function in our public API which takes a printf-style format string. We can add an annotation:

```
__attribute__((format(2,3)))
void print_warning(Context* ctx, const char* fmt, ...);
```

Now if you try to pass an int to a %f, or forget an argument, the compiler can emit a diagnostic at compile time just like with `printf` itself. I'm not going to go into each and every one of these, but taking advantage of them is a great way to get the compiler to catch bugs before they make it into production code.

Now for some self-promotion. Pretty much all this stuff is highly platform-dependent; whether a feature is available and how to use it properly can depend on the compiler, compiler version, the OS, and more. If you like to keep your code portable you end up with a lots preprocessor cruft to get it all right. To deal with this, I put together a project called [Hedley](https://nemequ.github.io/hedley/) a while back. It's a single header you can drop into your source tree which should make it a **lot** easier to take advantage of this type of functionality without making people's eyes bleed when they look at your headers.